# What is the roaring in a roaring fire?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics, air, everyday-life

I was just starting a barbecue fire by blowing on the smouldering coals when I realised I had no idea what the sound was actually caused by. I can make the sound by blowing at almost any flame I can think of, and I guess it is perhaps related to the increased oxygen consumption and a turbulent flow. Why does a disturbed flame make a sound?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The roar is indeed due to turbulence.

When a solid (or liquid) burns it isn't the solid that burns. The heat causes the solid to vaporise or emit vapour and it's the vapour that burns. When you have a steady flame the vapour burns smoothly. However, when you blow on it you make the vapour flow, and therefore the flame, turbulent. Under these circumstances the vapour burns as, in effect, a series of tiny explosions and this causes the roar.

I couldn't find a basic article on this subject (for once Wikipedia let me down), but if you Google for "flame turbulence sound" you'll find lots of scientific papers on the subject.

Comment: Rereading my answer this morning I realise I didn't mention that the turbulence mixes unburnt vapour with air, hence the "series of tiny explosions".

Comment: There's something more to this particular issue at play. I have been observing my new woodstove, and there is a moment right prior to "flame ignition" of a log where it is clearly hot enough that it is producing the vapours that will ignite, and all that is needed is a spark to ignite them. Yet somehow, the former is perfectly silent, whereas the latter is always accompanied by a dull wind sound. This occurs even though there is what looks like laminar flow from at least at a macro level. Are you implying that the turbulence occurs at a microscopic level?